# Finder won't quit

Tags: finder

Finder will not quit.  Hard reboot doesn't fix it.  I can't install updates because they require the computer to restart, and it will not restart with Finder open.

Comment: What version of MacOS? What happens when you try "Force Quit" (under the Apple menu). Do you have any third-party software installed that might cause Finder to crash or hang?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/243259/cannot-restart-mac-finder-issues-in-el-capitan Seems similar and might be the same issue. Hard to tell without an edit here with time details...

Comment: It's usually when things are too legit, they won't quit. I'm paraphrasing  MC Hammer, of course.

Comment: Have you tried going to Force quit under the Apple menu and clicking on the Finder?

Comment: @Allen, Funny reply.  But my comment was better - and you can't touch this...

Answer (score 1):

In order to properly quit finder, you need to open Activity Monitor. Once you’re in the app, select "Finder". Find the "x" at the top, and select "Quit" or "Force Quit".